# expect is not working for non-English language

Tags: shell, centos, expect

I am doing Postgres database auto backup on CentOS 7.9 using expect and shell code. My code is working fine in English environment but it fails in Japanese environment. Here is my expect code

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set homeDirectory "/home/kds/DB_BACKUP"
set dbPassword "manager"

log_file $homeDirectory/LOG/db_backup.log;

#Execute database backup script

spawn $homeDirectory/./backupexecutor.sh

set found 0
while {$found < 1} {
expect {
"パスワード: $"    {send "$dbPassword\r"}
"^Rollout Done "   {set found 1}
"^Rollout Updated " {set found 1}
}
}

expect eof
```

After checking the log file it is clear that expect cannot send password for `パスワード: $` keyword. I also tried `*スワー*` but same result. If change my OS language from Japanese to English and replace `パスワード` to `Password` the code works fine. Is there any way to work expect with a different language?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this to help, but `expect` uses `tcl` so you might get some info from its [i18n](https://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/i18n.html) doc page. Make sure you add to your post what you are setting in the environment as `LANG=` and so on, and what encoding your files are in.

Comment: That `$` character, is it intended as a literal character you expect to see, or is it a regex end-of-string anchor? If the latter, you're missing the `-re` flag.

Comment: Respond on the reasoning for $ for the expect clause

Comment: @glennjackman , by default `expect "something"` means `expect -gl "something"` and `$` also has the special meaning.

Comment: Incorrect. The glob special characters are enumerated [here](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) -- `$` is not among them. `$` only has special meaning in [regular expressions](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M25)

Comment: @glennjackman Expect uses Tcl does not mean it would handle something the same way as Tcl. You better refer to Expect's own doc.

Comment: I did: "By default, patterns are specified as with Tcl's string match command." and "Regexp-style  patterns  follow the syntax defined by Tcl's regexp (short for "regular expression") command."

Comment: @glennjackman Search for `^` and `$` in the manual -- `Both types of patterns are "unanchored" ... Use ^ to match the beginning of a string, and $ to match the end ... Note that in many editors, the ^ and $ match the beginning and end of lines respectively.  However,  because expect is not line oriented, these characters ...`

Comment: @glennjackman , you can simple try this: `expect -d -c 'spawn printf foo; expect "foo$" '`

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you.